# Extract certain data from multiple .txt files using Python and RegEx

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have several .txt files and I need to extract certain data from them. Files looks similar, but each of them stores different data. Here is an example of that file:

```
Start Date:        21/05/2016
Format:            TIFF
Resolution:        300dpi
Source:            X Company
...
```

There is more information in the text files, but I need to extract the start date, format and the resolution. Files are in the same parent directory ("E:\Images") but each file has its own folder. Therefore I need a script for recursive reading of these files. Here is my script so far:

```
#importing a library
import os

#defining location of parent folder
BASE_DIRECTORY = 'E:\Images'

#scanning through subfolders
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
        for filename in filenames:

        #defining file type
        txtfile=open(filename,"r")
        txtfile_full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        try:
            for line in txtfile:

                if line.startswidth('Start Date:'):
                start_date = line.split()[-1]

                elif line.startswidth('Format:'):
                data_format = line.split()[-1]

                elif line.startswidth('Resolution:'):
                resolution = line.split()[-1]

                    print(
                    txtfile_full_path,
                    start_date,
                    data_format,
                    resolution)
```

Ideally it might be better if Python extracts it together with a name of ech file and saves it in a text file. Because I don't have much experience in Python, I don't know how to progress any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code I've used:

```
# importing libraries
import os

# defining location of parent folder
BASE_DIRECTORY = 'E:\Images'
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
output = {}
file_list = []

# scanning through sub folders
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for f in filenames:
        if 'txt' in str(f):
            e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
            file_list.append(e)

for f in file_list:
    print f
    txtfile = open(f, 'r')
    output[f] = []
    for line in txtfile:
        if 'Start Date:' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
        elif 'Format' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
        elif 'Resolution' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
tabs = []
for tab in output:
    tabs.append(tab)

tabs.sort()
for tab in tabs:
    output_file.write(tab + '\n')
    output_file.write('\n')
    for row in output[tab]:
        output_file.write(row + '')
    output_file.write('\n')
    output_file.write('----------------------------------------------------------\n')

raw_input()
```

Comment: it also sorts text files alphabetically.

Comment: Great! I have the similar processing to be done.For example it has address field too which is spanned in multiple lines.how should I show it has come to an end ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expressions. You can use
basic string functions:

```
   txtfile=open(filename,"r")
   for line in txtfile:
         if line.startswidth("Start Date:"):
             start_date = line.split()[-1]
         ...
```

`break` if you have all information collected.

Comment: I have used your example in my code, but it still doesn't work. I think I haven't inserted it correctly, but I want python to read recursively through all the subfolders in the parent folder and extract all info at once.

Answer (score 0):

To grab the `Start Date`, you can use the following regex:

```
^(?:Start Date:)\D*(\d+/\d+/\d+)$
# ^ anchor the regex to the start of the line
# capture the string "Start Date:" in a group
# followed by non digits zero or unlimited times 
# followed by a group with the start date in it
```

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

regex = r"^(?:Start Date:)\D*(\d+/\d+/\d+)$"

# the variable line points to your line in the file
if re.search(regex, line):
    # do sth. useful here
```

See a [demo on regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/uU6rJ4/2).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The thing is that the date format is not always the same (e.g. `22 Sept.-18 Oct. 2003`), so I cannot really use this code.